# php mail() does not send email via xampp

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a html form that could send an e-mail to my email address, and here is my html code

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
<p>
    <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</p>
<p>
    <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</p>
<p>
    <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
```

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myemailform");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email 
address"); 
</script>
```

and here is my php code

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}
$email_from = &$visitor_email;
$email_subject = &$subject;
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "a@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
                        '(\r+)',
                        '(\t+)',
                        '(%0A+)',
                        '(%0D+)',
                        '(%08+)',
                        '(%09+)'
                        );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

however, when I launched apache in xampp, it didn't send the e-mail, do I have to run it in real server, or there is something wrong with my php code
any kinds of help will be appreciated

Comment: Is this on a Windows System

Comment: The Xampp are in localhost, i mean, you should open some ports for the SMPT ;)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: 1) windows does not come with a mail server  2) `mail()` does not send mail 3) all `mail()` does it pass a mail to a mail server, which you probably dont have. Therefore nothing send that mail

Comment: this is on mac system, thank you